# Excel Count rows where value in Column A has a duplicate in column B and that duplicate's other value in Column A equals something

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the table below:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | happy | 1-veggies | GHF |
| 1 | sad | 1-veggies | HGF |
| 2 | angry | 1-veggies | GHG |
| 2 | sad | 1-veggies | FGH |
| 3 | sad | 1-veggies | HGF |
| 4 | moody | 2-meat | FFF |
| 4 | sad | 2-meat | HGF |
| 5 | excited | 2-meat | HGF |

I need to count the number of rows where C="1-veggies", B="sad", A has a duplicate within A and whose alternative rows in A have a value in D = "GHF" or "FGH".

The result should be 1 based on the second row.

The second row has B= "sad", C = "1-veggies", A has a duplicate within A, whose value is "1" and the 1st row, also with A = "1" has a value in D = "GHF".

I already have a formula as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="sad")*(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)>1)*(C1:C8="1-veggies")*(D1:D8="GHF"))
```

However, it isn't able to check the 1st row nor does it check the necessary OR statement on column D.

I don't know how to accomplish either task. Thank you.

Comment: Would the duplicate row also need to have the values "sad" in the B-column and "1-veggies" in C? Or does that not matter?

Comment: I guess the  fourth row wouldn't count because although it contains FGH it's the same row as the sad 1-veggies row where A=2, not a separate duplicate row. I can kind of see how this might be done in SQL by a suitable self-join, but more tricky in Excel. Have you got Excel 365 with filters etc.?

Comment: @JvdV No, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe I do not have Excel 365

Answer (score 1):

Add some more COUNTIFS():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="sad")*(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)>1)*(C1:C8="1-veggies")*(COUNTIFS(A1:A8,A1:A8,B1:B8,"<>sad",D1:D8,"GHF")+COUNTIFS(A1:A8,A1:A8,B1:B8,"<>sad",D1:D8,"FGH")>0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to select rows where C="1-veggies", B="sad" and join them to rows where D = "GHF" or "FGH", but with a condition that the value in column A is equal in both but the row number is unequal. This might be a good use of Power Query for users who are expert in this, but using formulas is problematic because of the limitations of countifs (has to be a range). A workaround if you have Excel 365 would be to use some filters followed by countifs:

Column E

```
=FILTER(A1:A8,(B1:B8="sad")*(C1:C8="1-veggies"))
```

Coumn F

```
=FILTER(ROW(A1:A8),(B1:B8="sad")*(C1:C8="1-veggies"))
```

Column G

```
=FILTER(A1:A8,(D1:D8="GHF")+(D1:D8="FGH"))
```

Column H

```
=FILTER(ROW(A1:A8),(D1:D8="GHF")+(D1:D8="FGH"))
```

Then

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(E1#,G1#,F1#,"<>"&H1#))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have Excel 365. I'd be interested in the Power Query solution since that is part of Excel...

Comment: To be honest I don't think my power query skills are up to it - in particular, expressing a join on an inequality seems surprisingly difficult and poorly documented. I'm wondering whether to post a new question specifically on how to do this in Power Query, perhaps using your data if you don't mind? Or perhaps you would like to?

Comment: by all means! please share the answer you get!

Comment: Here is the question - I'm sure @Ron's comments are on the right track and will post an answer tomorrow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805148/join-on-inequality-in-power-query?noredirect=1#comment118091228_66805148

Comment: They seem to be missing the entire point is to COUNT the matches, not create a new table containing only the matches.

Comment: They are but two paths to the same destination.